# How to change SQL sever configuration manager settings using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, configuration

SQL server configuration manager is used to configure certain settings like connection protocols, service start up,  etc... 
Is it possible to make these changes that is done in SQL server configuration manager by using TSQL statements, or in the SSMS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most settings that can't be done via [sp_configure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx) are registry based

So, you can use [`xp_instance_regread`](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=xp_instance_regread) etc to change them. You'll have to find a list of registry keys yourself sorry but most are under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server`

One examples , protocols is under

```
...
...(instancename)\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp
...(instancename)\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Sm
...
```

and each of these has an `Enabled` value

One important note: you can stop SQL Server from xp_cmdshell or using [SHUTDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188767.aspx) but not start it of course...

Answer (score 4):

Going to have to go with the good ol' "it depends on what you want to do"

You could use the xp_cmdshell or powershell to change or start some options. For example if you want to start your SQL agent do this:

```
xp_cmdshell 'net start sql server agent (instancename)'
```

If you want to change server protocols with powershell, check out - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206997.aspx

Powershell is like it says, powerful.

Comment: I was looking at scripting these changes so that I can distribute it to the users, rather than being physically in front of the user's computer. Thanks for the powershell link.

Comment: If you set up powershell right, you can ship the scripts to use a txt file for specific parameters. Have the user just give it a nice little clickly click click and bam, you'll have your settings set up.